# Maximo Doclinks attachments should display in BIRT report

Tags: birt, maximo

Requirement:- Maximo Doclinks attachments should display in BIRT report

In BIRT report, we need to display DOCLINKS attachments without using any "Direct print with attachments" option in Maximo Report administration application. so that we can use the "with and without parameters" in report.

Issues we are facing when we use the "Direct print with attachments" option:

1. In Application, we need to select the list of records, and only for the selected records, the report will display the attachments. We are expecting attachments should be printed for all the hierarchy.
2. Also, we cannot add any parameters in report, when the "Direct print with attachments" option is enabled.

is this possible to write any logic to display the doclinks attachments (File type: doc,pdf,png,jpg) within the BIRT report?
Kindly guide me. Thankyou!